# How to create a left-join correctly in Python 2.7 with MYSQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to join 2 tables with left-join, but something is not oke with it.

I get this error code : `"You have an error in your SQL syntax to use near 'EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`', `\n`  `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, `\n`ARRIV`' at line 23"

Here my code :

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
        user='adam',
        passwd='',
        db='database1',
        use_unicode=True,
        charset="utf8")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """     select 
      `ACTUAL_TIME`, 
      `ACTUAL_DAY`, 
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, 
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`,     
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
      `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
      `SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
      `FLIGHT`, 
      `FROM`, 
      `AIRLANE`,
      `AIRCRAFT`, 
      `STATUS`, 
      `FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
      `FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
      `UPLOAD_TIME`
    from OSSZES as a
    left join (
      select 
        `ACTUAL_TIME`
        `ACTUAL_DAY`,
        COALESCE(`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, '') as EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE 
        `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`, 
        `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
        `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
        `SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
        `FLIGHT`, 
        `FROM`, 
        `AIRLANE`,
        `AIRCRAFT`, 
        `STATUS`, 
        `FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
        `FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
        `UPLOAD_TIME`
      from OSSZES_CLEAR
    ) as b using (`ACTUAL_DAY`,`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`,`FLIGHT`,`SCHEDULED_TIME`,`STATUS`)
    where b.EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE is null
    into outfile '/tmp/proba.csv'
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n';
        """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a` and `b` for fields.
For example if `ACTUAL_TIME` is from table `a`( OSSZES), use `a`.`ACTUAL_TIME`
and same goes for `b` table.

```
select 
  `a`.`ACTUAL_TIME`, 
  `a`.`ACTUAL_DAY`, 
  `a`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, 
  `a`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`,     
  `a`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
  `a`.`ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
  `a`.`SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
  `a`.`FLIGHT`, 
  `a`.`FROM`, 
  `a`.`AIRLANE`,
  `a`.`AIRCRAFT`, 
  `a`.`STATUS`, 
  `a`.`FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
  `a`.`FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
  `a`.`UPLOAD_TIME`
from OSSZES as a
left join (
  select 
    `ACTUAL_TIME`
    `ACTUAL_DAY`,
    COALESCE(`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, '') as EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE 
    `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`, 
    `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
    `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
    `SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
    `FLIGHT`, 
    `FROM`, 
    `AIRLANE`,
    `AIRCRAFT`, 
    `STATUS`, 
    `FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
    `FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
    `UPLOAD_TIME`
  from OSSZES_CLEAR
) as b using (`ACTUAL_DAY`,`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`,`FLIGHT`,`SCHEDULED_TIME`,`STATUS`)
where `b`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE` is null
```

Comment: Like this : ` a `.` ACTUAL_TIME ` or like this a.` ACTUAL_TIME `?

Comment: ` a` .` ACTUAL_TIME `

Comment: And where i have to use it? How you think it?

Comment: when you use join and aliases for tables like `a` and `b`, after that all the other fields should be in script like `a`.`field`, `b`.`field`.

Now you use only `fied` and do not have `a` (table name), which causes error as SQL can't understand what are you asking for.

Append table name (`a` or `b`) to each field in your script and it will work.
Before doing that, you can test it on some small script.

Join only 2 fields from one table and 2 from another and check if it will work

Comment: I dont understand where i have to write this part when i say a = OSSZES

Comment: mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`, \n  `a`.`ACTUAL_DAY`, \n  `a``EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, \n  `a``EXAMINED_AIRPORT_A' at line 2")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159372/discussion-between-giulio-bambini-and-harley).